# My html parser is not showing the entire HTML code that actually runs behind the webpage when I inspect the HTML code. Here's my code:

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import html5lib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Web Scraping\chromedriver.exe')

url = "https://ibegin.tcs.com/iBegin/jobs/search"

req = driver.get(url)

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('body', {'id' : 'app-body', 'data-country' : 'IN'}).prettify()

print(soup.find('div', {'class' : 'row custom-row searched-job ng-scope'}))
```

`

[image: HTML Parser's output]
[image: Actual HTML code]

I have tried finding the div tags hierarchically after the body tag. Still I am getting an empty list as output after this point. What have I been doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external source via JavaScript. `beautifulsoup` doesn't execute javascript, so you must use other methods to load the data. For example using their Api:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = "https://ibegin.tcs.com/iBegin/api/v1/jobs/searchJ"
payload = {
    "applyByOrder": None,
    "jobCity": None,
    "jobCityOrder": None,
    "jobExperienceOrder": None,
    "jobFunctionOrder": None,
    "jobSkill": None,
    "jobTitleOrder": None,
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "regular": True,
    "userText": "",
    "walkin": True,
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()


df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"]["jobs"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        id              jobTitle   location                functionName experience              applyByDate                                                               skills walkin   url
0  108544W  EP Recruitment Drive        NCR  IT INFRASTRUCTURE SERVICES        1-9  01-NOV-2022 12:00:00 AM                                              Java,Automation Testing      W  None
1  249335J                 PLSQL     Mumbai  IT INFRASTRUCTURE SERVICES        2-6  30-NOV-2022 11:59:59 PM                                                                PLSQL      J  None
2  249323J               SAP EWM      Delhi                  TECHNOLOGY       3-10  31-DEC-2022 11:59:59 PM                                                              SAP EWM      J  None
3  249321J            Oracle DBA     Mumbai  IT INFRASTRUCTURE SERVICES        2-6  30-NOV-2022 11:59:59 PM                                                           Oracle DBA      J  None
4  249320J              SAP ABAP       Pune                  TECHNOLOGY       3-10  31-DEC-2022 11:59:59 PM                                                             SAP ABAP      J  None
5  249319J     SAP HR Consultant      Delhi                  TECHNOLOGY       3-10  31-DEC-2022 11:59:59 PM                                                               SAP HR      J  None
6  249318J          Test Analyst  Bangalore                  TECHNOLOGY       4-10  31-DEC-2022 11:59:59 PM                                                                  POS      J  None
7  249317J               Network    Chennai  IT INFRASTRUCTURE SERVICES        4-8  30-NOV-2022 11:59:59 PM                               Network Security , Monitoring , Splunk      J  None
8  249315J          Network Data       Pune                  TECHNOLOGY        6-8  30-DEC-2022 11:59:59 PM  Network Admin , Routing,Switching , Wireless Networking & Protocols      J  None
9  249314J         Service Desk     Chennai                  TECHNOLOGY        3-5  30-DEC-2022 11:59:59 PM                                                         Service Desk      J  None
```